# Best way to store a dictionary of custom objects in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

I have a python script that is basically a team builder. However it is not running constantly as I am running it locally for now. I want users to be able to access their previously created team and so what would be the best way to store a dictionary of a custom object?

I have two classes, `Team` and `Character`. The `Team` class has an attribute that is a list of `Character` instances. And each `Team` is stored as a value in a dictionary with a user_id as the key.

Here is a basic outline:

```
master = {a_user_id:TrainerObject,another_user_id:TrainerObject,..}

class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.id = user.id # int
        self.name = user.name # str
        self.icon = user.icon # str, just a url link
        self.team = [] # List of Characters 

class Character:
    def __init__(self, slot, name, skills, item=None):
        self.slot = slot # int
        self.name = name # str
        self.skills = skills # dictionary of all str
        self.item = item # str
```

```
with open('master.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(master,f)
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command store:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/roopesh_m/Documents/Python/Coromon Battlesim/cogs/teambuild.py", line 565, in store
    pickle.dump(master,f)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

Edit: I have tried using pickle to store the dictionary, however I get a 'weakref' error when attempting to dump the dictionary

Edit2: Specified data types of class attributes

Edit3: Added pickle attempt and error

Comment: if you want to save to a file and you want to use a dict, just have the dict contain all the data to build the class, then you can use `json` and when you need to use some methods, create a class from the data

Comment: @Matiiss yeah so I wasn't sure if it was bad practice or not to like recreate the objects everytime

Comment: Can you tell what are the data types (int,str,etc) of each field in the classes?

Comment: Will update the code , sorry about that

Comment: you didn't mention `discord`, it may be that `discord` module can't be pickled, using the `json` won't be that much different in terms of loading objects at startup, but it will be safer and easier to read and you will need to only save the data not the objects themselves

Comment: The `discord` module doesn't affect any of the class attributes. The pickling code block itself is run by a discord command, hence the mention of the package. Yeah I might just use `json` and call it a day.

Comment: @Roopesh-J - the data types please - see my comment above.

Comment: @balderman i added them as comments in the code

Comment: @Roopesh-J Got it. I needed the data types on order to create a `dataclass`. See my answer.

Comment: [Your code works](https://tio.run/##jVPLasMwELzrK4RONpi8eimBHEJ7KqWF0J5KCIqtxGpkSUibQgj59nRXTtLmQal90KDZGc2ubL@B2tm7ex/2e914F4B7Xa6MYovgGl46Y1QJ2tnID7SVjapg7bGElUbGyN@C1FaFIeP4VGrBZzNtNcxmWVRmUfB1VCFvWXpos6MrPkoEoXOKDjiShC@EpbMnKeJzFpRskP2YHrM91DLIEv5IF42DInWFeKWNiQXXoJrRi7PqMjYVoz8tN0Nf520tSZPARTN4DlK0MEYtHSza@WbiHbdEwQXOKB1ADYucQTvwPlYfZp@ROOtj6ZOrLX90imQ1gB92u8aV0tQugsh/tKdRpUSnMWU91I2DdaZCh62QYsjFnMxKQpXY5cUNxbO2@KnYJFFUuCDJklAtdgjndCxGnx4DDC7DD7Dq1XxpyyduWcOv/L1Oev@TniYwNnMVIEXRFOCTrFaETIqCF4H0VRsknWxk20ND5QSFI@SxbYzOGhkhXdI2iftDfgzUug1OGwO2Y8wHbSFr/6dOtW58zFqHPN/vvwE).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `pickle`, a module in the standard library intended for this purpose.

```
import pickle


def save(save_file_path, team):
    with open(save_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(team, f)


def load(save_file_path):
    with open(save_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


# Example
save('version_1.team', master)
print(load('version_1.team')
```

You may need to handle some exceptions when loading if the file doesn't exist, but I left that out for simplicity. The reference for `pickle` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: I actually just tried using pickle, pretty much that first code block, and I get a 'weakref' error

Comment: @Roopesh-J Can you update your post with that attempt? Or link it over pastebin or something like that? You shouldn't really be seeing weakref errors here, there might be a problem with the data. But I can't tell from what's available to me.

Comment: The actual program is quite bigger and a bit more complex so I have simplified for the sake of this post but I don't think I have left anything vital out. I can include the code I ran to dump it and the error message itself

Comment: I could share all of the code perhaps but it may not help. For more context the `self.skills` attribute is a dictionary of all `str` data types. Both the keys and values are `str`.

Comment: Unless you have a circular reference or something really weird, you still shouldn't see that error. If you can, create a MWE that shows the `weakref` error and post that. Alternatively, if you want to use JSON, just add a method to return a class' attributes as a dictionary and a method to set them from a dictionary and just serialize to JSON.

Comment: I have planned and started the latter. I think you are right about the circular reference somewhere though, will debug more later on .

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataclass` + `dacite`. See the example below.

The code shows how we take a dict, convert it to a Trainer, back to dict and back to Trainer.

This is actually what you are looking for.

```
from typing import List,Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass,asdict

from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass
class Character:
    slot:int 
    name:str
    skills:str
    item:Optional[str]

@dataclass
class Trainer:
    id :int
    name:str
    icon:str
    team: List[Character] 

data = {'id':3,'name':'jack','icon':'something','team':[{'slot':9,'name':'Jim','skills':'well','item':'zoot'}]}

trainer = from_dict(data_class=Trainer,data=data)
print(trainer)
data = asdict(trainer)

print(data)

trainer = from_dict(data_class=Trainer,data=data)

print(trainer)
```

Comment: but this doesn't really store the object if I am understanding this correctly. It stores the attributes and its type. Like what about the methods of an object? I would have to just recreate the object anyways and in which case I could just use JSON right? I may be understanding wrong though, sorry in advance

Comment: The 2 classes you shared has no methods. Try to add a method to one of the and run the code. Does it work? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library, which performs relatively fast JSON (de)serialization. I timed it against `pickle` library below and looks like performance is mostly about the same.

> Note: below example should work on Python 3.7+ with the included `__future__` import

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import json
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from timeit import timeit

from dataclass_wizard import fromdict


@dataclass
class Trainer:
    id: int
    name: str
    icon: str
    team: list[Character]


@dataclass
class Character:
    slot: int
    name: str
    skills: dict[str, str]
    item: str | None


master = Trainer(12345, 'Johnny Smidt', 'The Great Icon 123',
                 team=[Character(7, 'Jim Raynor', {'A1': 'Catching Criminals'}, item='Pistol'),
                       Character(321, 'Tom Rebel', {'C3': 'Squirrel Hunting'}, item='Snare')],
                 )


def save(save_file_path, team):
    with open(save_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(team, f)


def save2(save_file_path, team):
    with open(save_file_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(asdict(team), f)


def load(save_file_path):
    with open(save_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


def load2(save_file_path):
    with open(save_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        return fromdict(Trainer, json.load(f))


# Example
n = 1_000
print('pickle -> save:    ', timeit("save('version_1.team', master)", number=n, globals=globals()))
print('dataclass -> save: ', timeit("save2('version_1.json', master)", number=n, globals=globals()))
print('pickle -> load:    ', timeit("load('version_1.team')", number=n, globals=globals()))
print('dataclass -> load: ', timeit("load2('version_1.json')", number=n, globals=globals()))

# assert that Trainer object loaded from pickle/json have the same data
assert load('version_1.team') == load2('version_1.json')

print()
print(load2('version_1.json'))
```

Results - tested on Mac OS Big Sur, running Python 3.10.0

```
pickle -> save:     0.18621111599986762
dataclass -> save:  0.38911844700032816
pickle -> load:     0.18183052699987456
dataclass -> load:  0.06633681200037245
```

Comment: Comparison with `pickle` is not correct, imho, not sure that it's needed though.

Comment: hmm interesting, these are actually the results I get on Mac OS at least

Comment: No, numbers are good, the idea is doubtful (imho). `pickle` is universal tool, so it's obvious that it'll be slower than specific one.